# Find real part of complex in Sympy matrix

Tags: python, sympy

I have this matrix obtain from `MyMat.eigenvals().keys()` from `sympy` (this are eigenvalues from 4D jacobian matrix):

```
egV = [5728761814608399/400000000000000 + sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/100000000000000000000000000000 - 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3) - 542870217167939624258689632311630767295785372177/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/200000000000000000000000000000 + 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)) + 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3))) - 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)))/2 - sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/200000000000000000000000000000 + 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)) + 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3))/2, 5728761814608399/400000000000000 + sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/100000000000000000000000000000 - 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3) + 542870217167939624258689632311630767295785372177/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/200000000000000000000000000000 + 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)) + 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3))) - 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)))/2 + sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/200000000000000000000000000000 + 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)) + 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3))/2, 5728761814608399/400000000000000 - sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/200000000000000000000000000000 + 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)) + 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3))/2 - sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/100000000000000000000000000000 - 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3) - 542870217167939624258689632311630767295785372177/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/200000000000000000000000000000 + 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)) + 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3))) - 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)))/2, 5728761814608399/400000000000000 - sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/100000000000000000000000000000 - 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3) + 542870217167939624258689632311630767295785372177/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/200000000000000000000000000000 + 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)) + 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3))) - 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)))/2 + sqrt(116481370240190604554434649577057/200000000000000000000000000000 + 84525541314107370029729686916824478617779085658015330937307969/(20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3)) + 2*(704966930593670936740277648541223935870775995019826163729310179922474354087956414591800649953/8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + sqrt(4176563721214961521026417694955136953714825217199604642869248664796023172422674692165308442655306961942463737618615469818663523407583102219569144299457956960070280847076949520807345)*I/50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)**(1/3))/2]
```

I would like to take only the real part so I try to use `re()` :

```
outMat = [re(eg) for eg in egV]
```

but it return this error :

> TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12583

Comment: Yes thanks, but I don't understand how it could help me to separate real and imaginary part...

Comment: I don't get any error in SymPy 1.3. Executing `[re(eg) for eg in egV]` returns the expression unchanged, while `[im(eg) for eg in egV]` returns zeros. It seems that all the eigenvalues are actually real, but SymPy is unable to rewrite them in a way that makes this evident (i.e., they still contain `I`). By the way, you can also use `re(egV)` or `im(egV)` or `egV.as_real_imag()` -- all these, when applied to a matrix, propagate to its entries.

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow using `egV.as_real_imag()` it work... but not with `re()`.... I do not understand why... but Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docstring of `re` function says

> Returns real part of expression. This function performs only elementary analysis and so it will fail to decompose properly more complicated expressions. If completely simplified result is needed then use `Basic.as_real_imag()` or perform complex expansion on instance of this function.

In SymPy 1.3, `egV.as_real_imag()` returns a tuple of matrices: real parts and imaginary parts. The imaginary parts are all zeros, which tells us that the eigenvalues are real. Apparently, the presence of `I` comes from [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis) of a cubic equation (the equation has three real roots, but an algebraic formula for them necessarily involves complex numbers).